# A Frankenstein Bride type movie

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have never been able to figure out which movie I saw, must have been early 70's on TV. I was very young and it scared the beejeezus out of me.  May be black and white.

Dr Frankenstein creates a bride for his monster, or at least a female monster. I remember vividly the bride was created from a young woman that was crushed by stampeding horses pulling a carriage.  Seems her head may have been severed, or at least she always wore a choker neckband to cover the scar.

The male monster pursues the 'bride', but she is in the high society social circles (she is not hideous as he is) and he can never have her.  The final scenes are at a social event, perhaps a ball, and the monster enters and rips her head off.  Big reveal. Monster mourns.

I can't ID it.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like [Frankenstein: The True Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein%3a_The_True_Story), (1973).  Jane Seymour plays Prima, (The Bride).

> Suspicious about the decorative neck choker which Prima insists on
>   wearing, Elizabeth spies on Prima as she sleeps and sees with horror
>   the stitches on her neck where her head has been attached.

And later:

> At that moment, Frankenstein's badly burned creature bursts into the
>   ballroom. Scattering the guests, he makes his way towards Prima. He
>   rips away the now savage Prima's neckband, revealing her neck scar to
>   the horrified crowd. After a tussle, where the guests try to keep a
>   crazed Prima from reaching the monster, he succeeds in literally
>   pulling off her head, dropping it at Polidori's feet. The ballroom is
>   left in chaos and destruction.

Comment: yup, that's definitely it. Mystery solved, thanks. how did you do that?

Comment: Hi @GScott.  The best way to thank someone is to "accept" their answer by clicking the checkmark/tickmark below the voting arrows.  Adding another "answer" is unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: Saw it when it first aired and never forgot it.